# Laravel 5.3 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Using Laravel 5.3 and Eloquent model, Trying to make a user role model.
the main schema that I have 2 tables **users** and **roles**, each user have a role and every role have many users (one to many relationship).

when i'm trying to make a foreign key in **user** table that references the id in **roles** table it gives me this error

> In Connection.php line 647:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   mydata.#sql-7e0_71 (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly
>   formed") (SQL: alter table "user" add constraint
>   "user_role_id_foreign" foreign key ("role_id") references roles("id"))
>
> In Connection.php line 449:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   mydata.#sql-7e0_71 (errno: 150 "   Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed")

**Note:** I'm using artisan command `migrate`, and I've tried these answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371608/mysql-laravel-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820305/laravel-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed)

here is my `up()` function for my **user** migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('role');
        });
    }
```

and for **role** table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Migration Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669880/laravel-migration-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed)

Comment: I changed the file name of the migration to change the order and it's working fine now

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a foreign key that have a reference on the `roles` table (`->on('roles')`), but in your migration file you are creating a table named `role` (`Schema::create('role', ...`). 
 You need to match those.

Either changed the name of the role table to `roles` or your reference to the `role` table.

Comment: it's a sample i forgot it here but it's written correctly on the real code